# Does SLS reuse any actual shuttle flight hardware besides engines?

Tags: reuse, sls, shuttle-derived

Will any SLS use flown (eg. SRB casings) or unflown (eg. ET tankage) hardware built for the shuttle program besides the engines (RIP)?

Comment: It's not exactly the same question, but the answer lists in detail which parts have flown.